# Remove List from List of List and generate a new List

Tags: python, list

The problem seems very easy, but unfortunately I can't solve it.

Let `list` `A = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9], [10,11,12], [13,14,15]]`

I want to create a new list by removing list `[7,8,9]`

The remove is not creating a new list: `A.remove(2)`

And `set(A) - set([7,8,9])` throwing the following error.

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

Can someone please help me to solve the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you absolutely need to remove based on index and not value, it may be done with a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
A = [value for i,value in enumerate(A) if i != 2]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
A = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9], [10,11,12], [13,14,15]]
A1 = A.copy()
A1.remove([7,8,9])

A1

# [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [10, 11, 12], [13, 14, 15]]
```

use it like this

Comment: This is not creating a new list. So, if I put `new_lst = A.remove([7,8,9])`. It's giving me value `None`

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution:

```
A = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9], [10,11,12], [13,14,15]]

# When B contain only 1 list
B = [7,8,9] 
C = [n for n in A if n != B]

# When B contains more than 1 lists
B = [[7,8,9]]
C = [n for n in A if n not in B]

# C = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [10, 11, 12], [13, 14, 15]]
```

Answer (score 0):

remove desired using remove function and assign it to another variable
newList = A.remove([7,8,9])

Comment: Please test your solutions before posting. The `.remove()` method operates in-place and returns `None`, so this is incorrect.

Answer (score -1):

A.remove() removes a element from a list, not index. you can use del a[2] instead

To create a new list i usally do:

```
import copy
newlist = deepcopy.copy(a)
newlist.remove([7,8,9])
```

Problem is a list is a pointer so therefor when creating

```
b = a
```

you simply just make a new pointer and not a new list. So by deepcopying you create a new address in memory

Comment: Your syntax for `deepcopy` is incorrect. And lists have their own `.copy()` method, which would be enough for the purposes of solving this question. It also makes a new address in memory.